# Remove duplicate lines but keep the one that does not have a string

Tags: csv, awk, duplicates

I have been looking for a while how to remove duplicates of my csv files. I started with a file with multiple fields but then I realize that I could just work with one file with 2 field and then merge the files using the first field. Here is what I want to do: I have this file [CSV file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ht34inj12j7te7x/genes.csv?dl=0) and as you can see there are genes with more than one description. Some of them have two descriptions, one is "hypothetical protein" and other is "something else". In that case I want to remove the one with "hypothetical protein" and keep the line with "something else". However, if there is more than one description, I can just keep the first one. I have been trying it with awk. It would be great if I could use awk for it.

Input example:

```
AAEL018330  hypothetical protein
AAEL018330  tropomyosin, putative
AAEL018331  hypothetical protein
AAEL018332  
AAEL018333  hypothetical protein
AAEL018333  colmedin
```

Output wanted:

```
AAEL018330  tropomyosin, putative
AAEL018331  hypothetical protein
AAEL018332  
AAEL018333  colmedin
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general (unsorted) case if you want to keep the last entry of a line by field you can use something like:

```
awk '{seen[$1]=$0} END {for (i in seen) {print seen[i]}}' file
```

Though that isn't guaranteed to keep sort order.

In this case, with sorted input something like this should work:

```
awk 'f!=$1 && line{print line} {f=$1; line=$0} END {print line}' file
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestions but there is no output. I had same problem yesterday when I was trying, I would either get a empty file as output or the original file.

Comment: @degopwn Are you trying to redirect the output to itself? `awk '...' < file > file`? Because other than that this should be working (and does on the sample data from the question). The first command had an error. I've just fixed it.

Comment: I just want to create a new file without the duplicates. So I use `awk '{seen[$1]=$0} END {for (i in seen) {print seen[i]}}' file1 > file2` So when I run it without specifying the output, it prints all lines that are duplicated. Even with your update I still get the same output. Thank you

Comment: @degopwn What you just wrote is what I edited my first suggestion to be. It works on your input here (and on http://www.compileonline.com/execute_awk_online.php). Can you include the output you are getting from these in your post?

Comment: here is the output file that I get [genes2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r541lghlh6jtn9k/genes2.csv?dl=0)

Comment: @degopwn So a number of things are wrong with that. Your pasted sample uses a different field delimiter than file itself. These answers all operate on the pasted sample not the csv file. You need `-F,` to tell awk to split on comma instead of space. Second, that file uses (oddly) a old-style mac line-endings (bare `\r`, not `\r\n` like Windows, or `\n` like Unix and that may be confusing awk as well (though I'm not sure about that).

Comment: yeah that was the problem. Thank you for helping. I downloaded the csv file from a genomic database and did not check what format was it.