# compare first 60 characters and delete the duplicate row

Tags: sed

How to use the sed to check the consecutive lines where there first 10 characters is the same?  If same,  the second row of the lines will be deleted.

Example:

Before

```
ABCDEF123456
123456ABCDEF
123456789012
123456789090
```

After

```
ABCDEF123456
123456ABCDEF
123456789012
```

Comment: My answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26599357/258523 has the basic concept I think you would want here. You just need to use a truncated `$0` instead of a specific field in the checks.

Answer (score 0):

This mihgt work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;P;/^\(.\{10\}\).*\n\1/d;D' file
```

Read two lines, print the first and then compare the first ten characters of the first line with the second line. If they are the same delete both lines otherwise delete the first.